# Using Sqlite3 as Redland RDF storage on iOS with Redland-ObjC

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios7, rdf, redland

I'm trying to use https://github.com/p2/Redland-ObjC, that compiles and runs fine on iOS to store RDF triples in the iOS sqlite3 database. However, documentation is very light, and Redland-ObjC seems to only use Redland storage with an in-memory hash table.

However, it's mentioned in the Readme of https://github.com/p2/Redland-ObjC that we might want to include libsqlite3 to use persistent storage.

Is it possible  ? If yes, how to tell Redland to use ios's sqlite3 API ? (I don't see any code in https://github.com/p2/Redland-ObjC that does that).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used the wrapper myself and my Objective-C is rusty, but reading the source suggests that you can do the following:

- Use something like `[RedlandStorage initWithFactoryName:@"sqlite" identifier:@"databasename.sqlite" options:@""]` to create a new sqlite storage object.
- Use something like `[RedlandModel initWithStorage:storage]` to create a new model using that `storage` as the backing store.  (The default `[RedlandModel init]` creates the model with the default in-memory `hashes` backing store.)

Then do whatever you would otherwise do with the model.

Comment: So I tried to do that, however, I get an error, Redland Error 0: {
    facility = 14;
    level = 4;
    locator = "<00000000>";
    message = "SQLite database db SQL exec 'BEGIN IMMEDIATE;' failed - (null) (21)"; I guess I need to create the database first somehow ?

Comment: Yep, if it doesn't exist yet, add `new='yes'` to the `options` string.

Comment: Thanks buddy, still the same error though, I will try to check redland sources to see whether it can natively access the ios sqlite database

Comment: I was missing librdf_storage_open(rdfStorage, [model wrappedModel]); that is not part of the obj-C wrapper of you have to get the C storage object (rdfStorage) from the wrapped version) Thank you for the indication new='yes' which I was also missing

Comment: At least with the C APIs, passing a storage to a model also opens the storage and opening it yourself is not necessary.